# In Azure AD, how to exclude a subset of users from requiring authentication info when first signing in

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

In my Azure AD tenant, I currently have it configured so that users logging in for the first time must register at least one authentication method (e.g. an alternate email, a phone number). This is useful for MFA and self-service password reset (SSPR) - [screenshot here](https://carlostransitfiles.blob.core.windows.net/sharefiles/passwordreset-registration.png).

I want to have several non-interactive service accounts that will **not** be configured for either MFA or for SSPR. Therefore, these non-interactive service accounts do not need alternate authentication methods. However, under my current setting, these service accounts are prompted to enter alternate authentication methods on first login:

- First with the "More Info Required" screen ([screenshot](https://carlostransitfiles.blob.core.windows.net/sharefiles/moreinforequired.png)), which you
  cannot cancel out of
- And then with the "don't lose access to your
  account!" screen ([screenshot](https://carlostransitfiles.blob.core.windows.net/sharefiles/dontloseaccess.png)), which actually does allow for the user
  to cancel the operation

This is extra inconvenient because, when adding an email, email verification is required, which doesn't allow us to do this programmatically ([screenshot](https://carlostransitfiles.blob.core.windows.net/sharefiles/email-verification.png)).

If I do just click "Cancel" on the "don't lose access to your account!" screen, I can simply proceed to sign-in without inputting alternate authentication methods ([screenshot](https://carlostransitfiles.blob.core.windows.net/sharefiles/afterclickingcancel.png)).

So the question is: **how can I exclude a certain subset of users (e.g. non-interactive service accounts) from requiring alternate authentication info when first signing in**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can include only a certain subset of groups for SSPR under Password Reset->Properties. This feature does not have an "Exclude" list, which makes it more difficult to implement.

More details in an MSDN forums post:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/51affd2c-a2c8-4faa-bbd8-bd1773c985d4/how-to-exclude-a-subset-of-users-from-requiring-authentication-info-when-first-signing-in?forum=WindowsAzureAD&prof=required